# Is there any more complete object reference for Rails than the API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometime it is a big problem to get to know, how to use all methods of an object. Is there a complete list of all possible parameters of all methods of all rails-objects?

For instance, when I looked for "belong_to", I found more complete information in tutorial  than in the API [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-belongs_to).
Where do the authors of Tutorial take their knowledge? Don’t tell they decompile hundreds of lines of source codes of each method.

I am not looking for a book. A complete reference is enough for me (similarly complete as a Ruby Language reference - e.g.

Comment: Have you check [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) ?

Comment: This is what I call a tutorial above. I looked for more complete information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked API Dock? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

I find their documentation to be very easy to read and it has a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, it seems to be exactly what I had looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, here it is - https://github.com/rails/rails/. Just read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to go through the links? `belongs_to` is alias for `references`, there is a link to [add_reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/ contains most complete docs for ROR